# Send Chef server events to syslog

Tags: chef-infra

we are now using Graylog2 for Logging Systemmessages. But now, I want to log all chef server messages to the syslog daemon. Didnt found any way and any config parameters.

Any idea here?

Comment: Here's a way to do it for chef-client ... https://github.com/higanworks-cookbooks/chef-client_syslog

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a recurent ([link1](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/COOK-2326) [link2](http://lists.opscode.com/sympa/arc/chef/2012-12/msg00329.html) [link3](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-1028)) question accross chef community.

The most common [solution](https://gist.github.com/mrtazz/3616423) is to add a new logger to chef, using the `syslog-logger` gem.

Another solution[5](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-1028?focusedCommentId=16618&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16618) uses `logger` shell built-in.

As mentionned by [@StephenC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c), there is a [cookbook](https://github.com/higanworks-cookbooks/chef-client_syslog) to make this automatic, but [this fork](https://github.com/gh2k/chef-client_syslog) seems more up to date.

I'll test them to provide more information regarding format (since chef logger is not especially syslog compliant).